# SQL Multi Table update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have 4 tables:

ContractedService

CarePackageLineItem

ContractedServiceLevel

Contract

They link together as follows:

```
select * FROM migrate.ContractedServiceLevel CSL
JOIN migrate.CarePackageLineItem CPLI
ON CSL.ServiceLevel = CPLI.ServiceLevel
JOIN migrate.ContractedService CS
ON CSL.ServiceRef = CS.ServiceRef
JOIN Migrate.Contract CON
ON CON.ContractRef = CS.ContractRef
```

What I need to do, is update all the service references, to be a concatenation of the first 2 characters of the contract reference, followed by the existing service ref.

Something like this:

```
SET ServiceRef = LEFT(con.ContractRef,2) + CS.ServiceRef
```

I tried to do this using regular updates based on the select statement above for each individual table, however that resulted in everything being the same service ref.  The reason I can't do a flat update, is because I need to split duplication of services (the duplicates are valid, but not for my ETL, hence the split), based on which contract they belong to.

I am fairly sure the answer is to use a CTE, but I am fairly unfamiliar with these and how to implement them.  The main thing here is referential integrity must be kept down the tables.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

I seem to have made a mistake in my initial joining of tables (though wouldn't affect the underlying question).  I have come up with a very over engineered solution to this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ServiceRefUpdate
(
CSLServiceRef varchar(100),
CSLID int,
CSServiceRef varchar(100),
CSID int,
ContractRef varchar(100),
ContractID int,
CPLIServiceRef varchar(100),
CPLIRef varchar(100),
)

INSERT INTO #ServiceRefUpdate
SELECT CSL.ServiceRef, CSL.RecordId, CS.ServiceRef, CS.RecordId,             
CON.ContractRef, CON.RecordId, CPLI.ServiceRef, CPLI.CarePackageLineItemRef
FROM migrate.ContractedServiceLevel CSL
JOIN migrate.ContractedService CS
ON CSL.ServiceRef = CS.ServiceRef
JOIN Migrate.CarePackageLineItem CPLI
ON CPLI.ServiceRef = CS.ServiceRef
AND CPLI.ServiceLevel = CSL.ServiceLevel
JOIN Migrate.Contract CON
ON CON.ContractRef = CS.ContractRef
JOIN migrate.ContractStructure CONS
ON CPLI.ServiceLevel = CONS.ServiceLevel
AND CON.ContractType = CONS.ContractType

UPDATE #ServiceRefUpdate
SET CSLServiceRef = LEFT(ContractRef, 2) + CSLServiceRef,
CSServiceRef = LEFT(ContractRef, 2) + CSServiceRef,
CPLIServiceRef = LEFT(ContractRef, 2) + CPLIServiceRef

UPDATE migrate.ContractedServiceLevel SET ServiceRef = UP.CSLServiceRef
FROM migrate.ContractedServiceLevel CSL
JOIN #ServiceRefUpdate UP 
ON UP.CSLID = CSL.RecordId 


UPDATE migrate.ContractedService SET ServiceRef = UP.CSServiceRef
FROM migrate.ContractedService CS
JOIN #ServiceRefUpdate UP
ON UP.CSID = CS.RecordId


UPDATE migrate.CarePackageLineItem SET ServiceRef = UP.CPLIServiceRef
FROM migrate.CarePackageLineItem CPLI
JOIN #ServiceRefUpdate UP
ON UP.CPLIRef = CPLI.CarePackageLineItemRef
WHERE UP.CPLIRef = CPLI.CarePackageLineItemRef

DROP TABLE #ServiceRefUpdate
```

Comment: Apologies, MSSQL, 2014 to be exact

Comment: In the last `update`: `ON UP.CPLIRef = CPLI.CarePackageLineItemRef WHERE UP.CPLIRef = CPLI.CarePackageLineItemRef` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that as well and did actually remove it after I pasted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit in my above post worked as desired.